# Putting a table next to a figure

Tags: tables, floats

I created a table and I would like to put a figure next to this table (see picture attached.

- The caption can be the same for both of them.
- I would probably need to increase the space between rows in order to align the table with the figure.
- The table can be positioned either right or left.

I leave you my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-1.5\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen}}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % <---
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
                    & Deterministic   & Stochastic \\
                    \midrule
Mean                & \euro430,96M        & \euro429,89M   \\
StDev               & \euro6,36M          & \euro5,44M     \\
n                   & 100             & 100        \\
\midrule
Best SP result      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro4,40M}  \\
Worst SP result     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{+\euro2,89M}  \\
Average performance & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro1,08M}  \\
t-test              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3,87E-10}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Analysis of the comparison between the SP and the deterministic model.}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.26]{SD5.png}}
\begin{changemargin}{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\vspace*{-1mm}
\caption{Analysis of the comparison between the SP and the deterministic model.}
\end{changemargin}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-8mm}
```

[image]

Comment: (i) please make your document example compilable, (ii) In attached picture has not any image, just a table.

Comment: @zarko, I hope this is better!

Comment: hm, you not correct your code. it is not compilable. Missing are  package for `EUR`, `begin{document} ,etc.

Comment: @Zarko, let me know if this works already, otherwise I will put all my packages (I just wanted to put the ones which could be useful).

Comment: Please, try to compile your document, which you provide and than see all errors which you will get. Anyway, an MWE (Minimal Working Example) with solution, for which I guess that you looking for, see in my answer below.

Comment: @Zarko, thank you for your help! I tried to do it and it almost worked (the picture is not aligned with the table), but then I realized that I already used newcolumntype C. I added now my whole code in order to avoid confusions. I hope this is clearer for you now. I would also like the image and the table to be split 50-50 among the text width. Is this possible?

Comment: @zarko, I created a new question in which  I show my result. I would be extremely grateful if you could take a look at it!

Comment: Tell me, what  is wrong with my answer? New question is just duplicate to this. In answer I insert a test image since I haven't your real image. You need just replace `example-image-duck`  with file name of the your image.

Comment: @Zarko, that is what I did, but the images are not aligned as I show in the other question.

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets The problem with making the image and tabular share the space 50/50 is that the tabular is of a fixed width, and is not flexible. It takes up more than half of the textwidth, and as it is now it can not fit 50/50 next to the image.

Comment: @TivV Exaactly, with the answer of Zarco I can only reduce the image width but the graph becomes too small. What is a way of put them 50-50?

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets I will add a way top do this as an answer. It includes resizing the tabular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. My point of view was to have the image and the table inside a `tikzpicture`.
   **The table is the content of a node**.
2. I scaled down the figure and table to have them side by side "without exceeding the margins".
3. You didn't provide the image, so I created it as a drawing in the `tikzpicture` environment.  If you want to use it, change the code and use `includegraphics` in the content of a node.  In general, if possible, draw instead of include!
4. In the code below, I kept only the commands needed for the compilation. At first sight, your preamble seems heavy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \tikzmath{real \r; \r=2.1; }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
    \fill[green!30!black] (0, 0) circle (\r);
    \fill[gray!40] (0, 0) -- (\r, 0) arc (0:90:\r) -- cycle;
    \path (\r*.45, \r*.4)
    node[text width=8em, align=center, scale=.7] {Deterministic 25\%};
    \path (-\r*.45, -\r*.4)
    node[white, text width=6em, align=center, scale=.7] {\textbf{Stochastic 75\%}};
    
    \path (\r+.5, 0) node[right, scale=.9] {%
      \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        & Deterministic & Stochastic \\
        \midrule
        Mean                & \euro430,96M  & \euro429,89M   \\
        StDev               & \euro6,36M    & \euro5,44M     \\
        n                   & 100           & 100        \\
        \midrule
        Best SP result      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro 4,40M}  \\
        Worst SP result     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{+\euro 2,89M}  \\
        Average performance & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro 1,08M}  \\
        t-test              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3,87e-10}\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Analysis of the comparison between the SP and the deterministic model.}
  \label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: tahnk you for your answer. Nevertheless, if possible, I do not want to change the width of my text (I have already written 100 pages). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can scale down the drawing (disk and everything)  and the table.  In the node options, you use scale=.8 for example.  Verify the result and try again.  If it is not clear, I can modify the code later this evening.

Comment: OK.  I modified the code.  It works with the basic LaTeX layout for the page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you looking for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}             % <---
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % <---
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c X @{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3 \linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    &   
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \toprule
        & Deterministic   & Stochastic \\
                    \midrule
        Mean                & \euro430,96M  & \euro429,89M   \\
        StDev               & \euro6,36M    & \euro5,44M     \\
        n                   & 100           & 100        \\
        \midrule
        Best SP result      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro 4,40M}  \\
        Worst SP result     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{+\euro 2,89M}  \\
        Average performance & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro 1,08M}  \\
        t-test              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3,87E-10}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Analysis of the comparison between the SP and the deterministic model.}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really think the O.P. is looking for a duck? :-)

Comment: @Bernard, of course not :-).  He need to insert correct image which I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tabular and image to take up the same amount of vertical space, you have to resize the tabular, as in your version it takes up more than half of the space. (In principle, I agree with @Zarko's answer to just resize the image and leave the tabular alone.)

Here is one way to resize the table - using a `resizebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
text text text text text

\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X X @{}}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
        
        &
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
                \begin{tabular}{lcc}
                    \toprule
                    & Deterministic &    Stochastic    \\ \midrule
                    Mean                & \euro430,96M  &   \euro429,89M   \\
                    StDev               &  \euro6,36M   &    \euro5,44M    \\
                    n                   &      100      &       100        \\ \midrule
                    Best SP result      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro 4,40M} \\
                    Worst SP result     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{+\euro 2,89M} \\
                    Average performance & \multicolumn{2}{c}{-\euro 1,08M} \\
                    t-test              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3,87e-10}     \\ \hline % or \bottomrule to keep in theme with toprule and midrule...
                \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Analysis of the comparison between the SP and the deterministic model.}
    \label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that this takes the whole table and shrinks it, thus resulting in a smaller font size and thickness of rules, potentially looking a bit out of place (which is why I prefer Zarko's answer).

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! I do not why, but the table and the figure do not get aligned.. I had the same problem with Zarko answer... I am using Overleaf, could it be the root of the problem?

Comment: Try copying this exact code just to test it. If the problem remains, maybe you changed something in the preamble?

Comment: Please keep in mind that using resizebox on a tabular will result in inconsistent font sizes throughout the document.